# Why can I login to my database using my .pgpass credentials, but not use pg_dump?

Tags: linux, postgresql

After updating my computer I am unable to do automatic backups of my PostgreSQL 12 database, which has the version:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.8 (Ubuntu 12.8-Ubuntu0.20.04.1)
```

Before updating, I was able to run the following code, both manually and using crontab:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U brian -d example_db > '/home/brian/.../example_db.bak'
```

The error I now get is:

```
pg_dump: error: connection to database "example_db" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "brian"
password retrieved from file "/home/brian/.pgpass"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "brian"
password retrieved from file "/home/brian/.pgpass"
```

I have confirmed that my ".pgpass"-file lives up to the manual described here:
[PostgreSQL 12 Manual: pgpass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/libpq-pgpass.html)

I am also able to log in to my database without being prompted for a password:

```
brian@pc:~$ psql -U brian -d example_db
```

Would anyone have an idea why I am unable to use pg_dump when I am able to login to my database without being prompted for my password?

Comment: Try the `psql` with the same `-h` and `-p` options as `pg_dump` - it's almost certainly connecting over unix socket rather than tcp and probably has different authentication set. Then rename your pgpass file and try manually typing the password. That way you will know if the password in the file is correct.

Comment: thank you! I tried to rename the pgpass-file, but it didn't change anything with regards to logging in. I then tried to manually set my password once more in psql and that solved my problems and allowed me to log in using the pgpass-file again.

Comment: How did you update?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - I updated the password inside the psql environment, as described in the manual that I linked :-)